# Need to download a PDF using a url

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, download, imacros

I have a link to a page which has an embedded PDF. I want to download that pdf file using any code, but i cant. The only way to download it is by clicking on the download button, or setting the mozilla preferences to auto-download.

But that does not satisfy my need. I have tried using python, javascript, but still not able to download it.

Can someone please show me a way to get a pdf downloaded by any method?
(preferably being able to specify your own directory/file name)

Comment: Show some code. What you have tried ?

Comment: Can you the post the which has PDF?

Comment: If there's a download button then there's a high chance there's a direct url for the .pdf Inspect the source of the page, find that URL. Might get you started.

Comment: thanks @JoeSmart. I actually did get a link that ends in ".pdf"
so i then used the wget for python and downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading files with Python:

```
sudo pip install pattern
```

download.py:

```
from pattern.web import URL

url = URL('http://www.nytimes.com/images/2014/09/03/nytfrontpage/scan.pdf')
f = open('nytimes.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(url.download(cached=False))
f.close()
```

run:

```
python download.py
```

Comment: thanks @Moogs. i had tried that exact code earlier, but it did not work out.
Only the top bar that is in HTML gets converted to pdf but the actual pdf file below it, does not get added.